# Which is Android/Java corresponding method to the C#/C++ method GetTickCount()?

Tags: c#, java, c++, android

I wanna know a corresponding method in Android/Java that is like the GetTickCount method in C#/C++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Android it is [SystemClock.uptimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29).
Please note that `uptimeMillis()` does not include time spent in deep sleep. You may need [SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) for total time after boot.

Comment: Thanks, will check this soon!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer gives the milliseconds since boot, but the answer for me is `System.currentTimeMillis()`. This gives you the number of milliseconds in UTC since January 1, 1970. This is the equivalent of what GetTickCount method does.

Comment: GetTickCount() does not have anything to do with UTC (referring to the Windows API). It is the time elapsed since system start.