# Android NDK LoadLibrary("KERNEL32.DLL")

Tags: android, c++, dll, android-ndk

Is there a way to Load the kernel32.dll library in the Android NDK?

I'm trying to extract the GetTickCount and GetTickCount64 functions out of it, and I get this error when trying to run the LoadLibrary("KERNEL32.DLL"):

```
Function 'LoadLibrary' could not be resolved
```

Any suggestions to get the GetTickCount and GetTickCount64?

Comment: As in the *Windows* kernel? That seems unlikely on Android

Comment: Is there then another way to get the same functions? Or make the functions in C++ without the libraries?

Comment: [Which is Android/Java corresponding method to the C#/C++ method GetTickCount()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590089/which-is-android-java-corresponding-method-to-the-c-c-method-gettickcount)

Comment: Yeah but I need it in C++ so it can just run with the rest of the library in the NDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is Linux, not Windows. You need to use Linux APIs. Use `clock_gettime` instead of `GetTickCount` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958359/632035)).

Comment: I know Android is not windows or osx...
I'll try the clock_gettime function and see where I end up. Thanks